# High resolution image upload fails stream_copy_to_stream(): read of 8192 bytes

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx

I am using laravel + twill inside docker containers with php7.4.3-fpm + nginx. Everything works fine appart from when I am trying to upload images of high resolution. If I upload image of 3000x3000px there are no problem as soon as I try to do the same with higher resolution (4500x4500px) I get the following error,

```
message: "stream_copy_to_stream(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory"
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/backend/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php"
line: 159
trace: [{function: "handleError", class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions", type: "->"},…]
0: {function: "handleError", class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions", type: "->"}
function: "handleError"
class: "Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions"
type: "->"
1: {file: "/var/www/backend/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php", line: 159,…}
file: "/var/www/backend/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Adapter/Local.php"
line: 159
function: "stream_copy_to_stream"
```

Is it a php-fpm configuration issue? Is it problem with php? Has anyone had similar problems?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same problem on php7.4 + nginx at docker

Comment: I am having same issue with linux 18 apache php7.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find a solution, my problem was with php.ini setting, how lame of me to overlook it.
I fixed it by adding these to the docker entry file.

```php
sed -i -e "s/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 64M/g" $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
sed -i -e "s/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 64M/g" $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
sed -i -e "s/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 256M/g" $PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini
```

Comment: Hello I am facing same issue I am on ubutu18

Answer (score 3):

These steps solved the same issue for me!

1. Open file /etc/php/7.*/fpm/php.ini
2. Edit upload_max_filesize
3. Edit post_max_size
4. reload php7.*-fpm service

good luck!